# PostScript font not found

Tags: fonts, installing, postscript

After switching to a new MikTeX installation on a new computer, I am having a problem with an additional PFB font. The font used to work on the old computer, but I can't see why it doesn't work on the new computer.

I installed MikTeX 2.9 for x64.

1. I placed a map file astr1.map with the following text content

   ```
    astr1 LAstrologyPi-One <astr1___.pfb
   ```

   into a new subfolder "astrology" of C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips
2. For specifying the font, I use the TeX command

   ```
   \font\as=astr1
   ```
3. The file `astr1___.pfb` is in a new subfolder "astrology" of folder C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1
4. In C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config, I appended at the end the following line:

   ```
    Map astr1.map
   ```
5. In a command shell, I started `updmap`
6. After that, I started `initexmf --admin -u`

When starting TexWorks and processing the TeX command `\font\as=astr1`, the console logs:

```
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The astr source file could not be found
```

Later on, the font cannot be used. I was able to process the same TeX document in an older release on an older machine, however.

Why does it log "astr not found" and not "astr1 not found"? Is there a (new) problem with trailing digits in font names?

Is my procedure correct so far (I want to install the font in the admin branch, not in the local branch of the file system)?

What is going wrong?

Can I inspect a list of all installed fonts that are available on my MikTeX installation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 2):

map files should go into `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips`

Comment: Thanks. I created `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\astrology\astr1.map` and updated everything in admin mode. The result remained the same `miktex-makemf: The astr source file could not be found` as the TeX statement `\fonts\as=astr1` is to be processed.

Comment: Did you updated the file name data base with the MiKTeX setup?

Comment: Yep. After the described change, I issued `initexmf --admin --update-fndb`, then `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap`, then `initexmf --admin --mkmaps` and finally again the update-fndb. I checked the font existence with the tex standard file `tex testfont`, entering `astr1`. The same message was issued as reported above (this is the message that also comes when entering a bogus font name like `dasdad`). On the other hand, the map file `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/map/dvips/astrology/astr1.map` is correctly detected with `kpsewhich astr1.map`. What's happening?

Comment: Why is the trailing `1` of the font name `astr1` swallowed in the error message (`The astr source file could not be found`) ? Does this give any clue?

Comment: `\fonts\as=astr1` that is not possible, the LaTeX  name of the font must have only letters. Use `astr LAstrologyPi-One <astr1___.pfb` for the map file

Comment: I changed precisely this: `astr LAstrologyPi-One <astr1___.pfb` in the map file, leaving everything else, even the file name `astr1.map` as it was. Then the `initexmf ... ` steps as above. Result: `The astr source file could not be found.`...

Comment: Changing filename `astr1.map` to `astr.map` is of no effect either.

Comment: the filename `astr1.map` is ok. What happens, if you use in your document in the preamble `\pdfmapfile{astr1.map}`?

Comment: Inserting `\pdfmapfile{astr1.map}` before using `\font\as=astr` (both before `\begin{document}`) doesn't help. The log is: ...`{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/map/dvips/astrology/astr1.map}(/amac.texRunning miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The astr source file could not be found.`...

Comment: You have no tfm file for this font, right?

Comment: I _do_ have a TFM file (I forgot to mention that in the question). It is stored as `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\astrology\Astr1___.tfm`

Comment: is it a typo ? `Astr1` the A instead of a. However, now I am lost

Comment: Windows file location is case insensitive. I changed `A` to `a`, and as expected it didn't change the system behaviour. Thank you anyway, Herbert, for your valuable hints.

Answer (score 2):

A trailing '1' in the symbolic font name is not allowed. I used `astr1` as symbolic font name in the map:

```
astr1 LAstrologyPi-One <astr1___.pfb
```

This used to work in my earlier MikTeX release (2.7) but is not valid in 2.9 any more.

Changing the map to

```
astr LAstrologyPi-One <astr1___.pfb
```

additionally requires the name of the TFM file to be adapted: It works if the TFM file name is made equal to the symbolic font name (`astr.tfm`), not to the real font name (`astr1___.tfm`).

For the details, see the comments to Herbert's answer above - he was just one minute before the complete solution! Thanks again, Herbert.